# React/Rails - getInitialState not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I'm following [this intro to React guide](http://rny.io/rails/react/2014/07/31/reactjs-and-rails.html) as well as the original [fb react tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), using Rails as a backend. I've split out my files and they all work together correctly up to [this point](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server).

Upon trying to set the `getInitialState` to provide props for my `CommentBox`, I get errors of `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, meaning React can't find the empty array `[]` that was allegedly set, and sent to `CommentList`. How do I ensure `getInitialState` actually sets the `data` prop?

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {data: []};
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1> Comments! </h1>
        <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ready = function(){
  React.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
};

$(document).ready(ready);
```

Then entirety of the code is hosted in [this repo](https://github.com/maxArturo/rails-react/tree/example). Thanks!

EDIT: CommentList code:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  commentNodes: function(){
    var nodes = this.props.data.map(function(d){
      return(
        <Comment author={d.author}>
          {d.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return nodes;
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="commentList">
        This is the comment list.
        {this.commentNodes()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Essentially:

- I was trying to pass in a `data` props, which doesn't exist because it is a *state*.
- Upon rendering the `CommentList`, it then becomes a `prop` and it can be accessed from there.

Learnings were had.

Comment: FYI you should tag your own answer as accepted so other can see that this question was answered :)

Comment: Thanks! Will do in 20 hours. :)

Comment: Hah, I've been less active on SO the last couple of years, I forgot about that rule.